# Showing sticky posts with get_posts()

Tags: loop, get-posts, sticky-post

I'm using this to retrieve posts on my index page:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts( "category=13&numberposts=2" ); ?> 
<?php if( $posts ) : ?>
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 

[code]
```

Is there a way to include sticky posts on loops like that one? Or I'll have to use WP_Query?

Comment: That will include sticky posts, if they are in the category you pick. Are you trying to include sticky posts in addition to the category you choose?

Comment: `get_posts()` takes the same parameters as `WP_Query()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters

Comment: I would like to get the sticky posts of each category.